# .NET CQRS Frameworks nCQRS vs Lokad.CQRS

Tags: .net, cqrs

For the last couple of weeks I've been reading up and watching any resources I can find on CQRS. I really like the concept and am keen to start delving deeper. I have only found 2 major .NET frameworks for CQRS and I am trying to evaluate the differences between them.

I am looking to implement CQRS on a noSql db, most likely RavenDB.

Lokad seems very focused on windows Azure, not sure if it supports Raven. It has extensive documentation but not a lot of activity in the community. nCQRS has a lot of activety and supports Raven.

I was wondering if anyone has any experience working with these two frameworks and what the major differences are between them.

Comment: BTW, Lokad.CQRS is no longer focused on Windows Azure. It has got portability mode, that allows it to run on any Windows OS without any external dependencies in a persistent mode (MSMQ is not needed either)

Comment: Last time I looked nCQRS was going a terrible direction of trying to tick all the boxs of something off an Microsoft "Enteprise solution", including introducing code contracts that basically ground the IDE to slow painful crawl. You probably find you dont need either you can still adopt command query separation attitude without the sledgehammer frameworks, thing carefully before going this route. I went back to basics and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Besides "CQRS" solutions, what's often applied is an ESB (Enterprise Service Bus). CQRS is all around messaging and these types of frameworks exist around messaging.

- MassTransit http://masstransit-project.com/, https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit
- NServiceBus http://www.nservicebus.com/, https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus
- Eh, BizTalk, sorta.

MassTransit is Apache2 licensed. NServiceBus is LGPL/Commercial for the latest releases, I think you can get older under a more permissive license. BizTalk isn't a great solution and it's whatever Microsoft charges for it.

Some of the info from http://cqrsinfo.com/documents/cqrs-introduction/ might be of use in developing solutions around this as well.

http://twitter.com/#!/ackenpacken has a in process message dispatcher he uses. I'm not sure if it's out there anywhere but I've seen it :) For fun his latest example I saw had the consumers implementing `ICanHaz<T>`.